# What is the difference between yellow journalism and sensationalism?

Tags: journalism

I understand there is some overlap between the two concepts, but I don't understand the distinction.

Comment: Please could you give more information about what you do understand and where the definitions confuse you.

Comment: If this has to do with writing/journalism, it's on-topic, but just asking for a definition isn't on-topic here. Kyle, can you please give more information as Matt has requested?

Comment: On hold until we get more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two things are probably more similar than you think they are.

[*Yellow journalism*](https://history.state.gov/milestones/1866-1898/yellow-journalism) is a broader term for any kind of journalism that doesn't include any actual facts or research. It can include blatantly false information, and usually relies solely on exaggeration, dramatic images and headlines, and scare tactics.

*Sensationalism* is exaggeration, dramatic images and headlines, and scare tactics, among other things. It's the act of trying to catch the mass public's attention with deliberately shocking, scandalous, etc. stories that may not actually be what would be considered "news".

There's a lot of overlap. I guess the distinction, if there is one, is that "yellow journalism" is a type of journalism, while "sensationalism" is a journalistic tactic.

Comment: One more distinction may be that while Sensationalism will usually pick actual facts and then wildly misrepresent them (e.g. providing ludicruous predictions of their consequences or drawing other outrageous unfounded conclusions); also it doesn't bother with fact-checking often presenting gossip or speculation as fact, Yellow journalism may entirely fabricate even the base facts. In sensationalism there's a grain of truth somewhere down below under the hype blown out of proportion; in Yellow journalism there may not not even be that much, the whole story entirely made up.

Comment: So yellow journalism is libel, sensationalism maybe not?